# Retrieve data from sharepoint

Tags: reactjs, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have created a react app ,able to log users in and so on, I want to use their login name to fetch a folder in sharepoint with there name on it and display that data. I want to call an api and retrieve the data ,read articles talkink about PnP and Spfx but not managing. All im getting is creating somethin in sharepoint , just want to retrieve the data and send data to the specic folder.Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: Is it from an spfx webpart, or any client reactjs app

Comment: from client reactjs app @Muhammad Murad Haider

Comment: you could use `sp-pnp-js` to interact with SharePoint. check : https://spblog.net/post/2017/06/07/Using-PnP-JS-Core-(sp-pnp-js)-in-Nodejs-environment